# Elasticsearch Setup Custom Index and Write Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Elasticsearch get logs via filebeats shipper default settings. All custom index settings were configured on `/etc/filebeats/filebeats.yml` file. This is my configuration file:

```yaml
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["host-ip:9200"]
  protocol: "https"
  index: "samba-%{[agent.hostname]}-%{[agent.version]}-%{+dd.MM.yyyy}"
  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  username: "elastic"
  password: "password"
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    certificate_authorities:
      - |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
       XXX
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----

setup.template:
  name: "samba"
  pattern: "samba-%{[agent.version]}"
  overwrite: true

setup.ilm.enabled: false
```

When the filebeat setup command was run, `"no matching index template found for data stream [samba]"` exception was thrown, **although this custom index template was created on ELK**. After start the filebeat service, all logs were collected on default index (.ds-filebeat-8.6.2-2023.03.09-000001).

**UPDATE:**
Briefly, this is api call output:

```json
{
    "index_templates": [
      {
        "name": "samba",
        "index_template": {
          "index_patterns": [
            "samba-8.6.2"
          ],
          "template": {
            "settings": {
              "index": {
                "mapping": {
                  "total_fields": {
                    "limit": "10000"
                  }
                },
                "refresh_interval": "5s",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "max_docvalue_fields_search": "200",
                "query": {
                  "default_field": [
                    // other fileds.
                    "fields.*"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "mappings": {
              "_meta": {
                "beat": "filebeat",
                "version": "8.6.2"
              }
              // about 30.000 line is removed by use vscode ide.
            }
          },
          "composed_of": [],
          "priority": 150,
          "data_stream": {
            "hidden": false,
            "allow_custom_routing": false
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the template ?

Comment: The Samba template is so long, with mapping statements.  If you want, I can share index settings only? Actually, template looks a like default filebeats template.

Comment: I do not need the mapping, but I would like to check the `index_patterns` and other settings

Comment: I can't any `index_pattern` field name on index template review json. Actually, when all mapping statement is exclude, the template seems like very empty. But I will update my question.

Comment: I am confused, can't you paste the content of this api call ? `GET /_index_template/<name of the samba index template>`

Comment: Sorry for late but i must arrange api call output. I made what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tldr;

The error says `no matching index template found for data stream [samba]`, and indeed the pattern you have is `samba-%{[agent.version]}`

## Solution

Change the pattern to `samba*`
So your file should look like

```yaml
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["host-ip:9200"]
  protocol: "https"
  index: "samba-%{[agent.hostname]}-%{[agent.version]}-%{+dd.MM.yyyy}"
  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  username: "elastic"
  password: "password"
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    certificate_authorities:
      - |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
       XXX
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----

setup.template:
  name: "samba"
  pattern: "samba*"
  overwrite: true

setup.ilm.enabled: false
```

Comment: i changed pattern statement but not working although before I removed ex index and template.

Comment: Might be because I forgot about the `-` in the pattern.

Comment: Yes, setup finished without error but 'samba-hostname-version-date' index was not created. Instead of our index pattern, hidden ".ds-samba-2023.03.09-0001 index was created.  So actually completely was not solved.

Comment: Well you question was about fixing the error, which is done.

Now your index name is wrong, I am pretty sure you can change it in the `name` section of the configuration but this is another topic/question

Comment: Thanks a lot for requests @Paulo, you are right, when the statement was changed like `name: "samba-aclient1-%{[agent.version]}"`, index was created. But why the index is hidden? I will ask another question.

Comment: Awesome glad it worked, you are working with datastream I suppose I might want to look at the documentation for datastream they are a special kind of indices